# location of pointers in Objective C instances

Tags: objective-c, reflection, decomposition

I am designing automatically persistent objects, and for that I need (a) to locate members which are pointers, (b) to find their locations. The compiler has this information, and I expected that the reflection would provide it, but I cannot figure out how to do it. For example, if an object starts at address 505060

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

  NSString *name; // class offset 4B,  member address 505064
  int code;
  MyClass *next;  // class offset 12B, member address 505072
}
@end
```

Comment: typo: member addresses should be 505064 and 505072

Comment: just for curiosity: what do u need this information for?

Comment: What about the members of the superclass?

Comment: Re-inventing persistency is an interesting pursuit, but it would be exceptionally rare that there is any need to do so for any reason beyond academics.

Comment: (1) For every class, I generate a mask which is like a zero-filled instance with pointer locations (typically 4B) marked by one. Right now,this is done by providing a simple method listing all kinds of

Comment: I am writing a book on serialization and persistent objects. This is a new hot topic, and goes far beyond archiving which requires lot of manual interaction. For example, I can allocate all objects from pages of memory, and save them in one shot without looking at individual objects. When reading the data from disk, I only convert

Comment: ... continue: pointers which I can identify from the mask. This method is similar to what ObjectStore is using for their persitent data and OO databases.

Comment: You're writing an engineering book about a topic you don't know very well...?

Answer (score 6):

The location of an ivar relative to its owning object's address is an implementation detail. While it's a *well-defined* implementation detail, there are very few real-world reasons to know an ivar's offset.

If you *really* need to know where an ivar is, take a look at the Objective-C runtime functions `class_getInstanceVariable()` and `ivar_getOffset()`. However, if you tell us what you're trying to do, we may be able to suggest a smarter approach to solving your problem.

Comment: This gives me the locations, but I do not know how to detect which variables are pointers. Do you?

Comment: Detecting which ivars are pointers is a different question from the one you originally asked. It also doesn't sound very sane--why do you want to do it? What do you think you will accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily obtain the address of a field by getting a reference to it:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{    
  NSString *name; // class offset 4B,  member address 50564
  int code;
  MyClass *next;  // class offset 12B, member address 50572 
} 
@end


void *pointer = &name;
```

Or you can use directly the ObjectiveC runtime (see Jonhatan answer)

But **this is not how persistency should be implemented in ObjectiveC**, for this you have `NSCoding` and such things. Going low level with ObjectiveC instances which have vtables and such is not a good idea. If you really want to implement persistency at a low level I suggest you to use something like a [memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) pattern to have an internal state which is separated from the implementation and that can be implemented purely in C.

Comment: Reflection surely does exist in Objective-C. It's just not used very often.

Comment: It does, but not for addresses of fields. Of course it does exist, otherwise you wouldn't be able to catch __no such selector__ errors. Address of fields are a lower level compared to ObjectiveC itself, so that's true even for reflection.

Comment: Sure it does. `ivar_getOffset()`.

Comment: That's not ObjectiveC, that's C indeed.

Comment: Reflection does exist. Objective C has a runtime because it is C with Scala(?). Hence why this doesn't fail: `[nil nil];`. There is a runtime. A runtime = reflection.

Comment: Please read my answer: I've never said reflection doesn't exist. I said that it doesn't exist directly in ObjectiveC to let you know the address of a field, that's why you go with the ObjectiveC runtime itself (ivar_getOffset()) or directly in C.

Comment: `ivar_getOffset()` is part of the Objective-C runtime, which is exposed as a set of C functions. This is still part of Objective-C, which comprises both a syntax and a runtime library. C is Objective-C; the latter is a superset of the former, so all valid C is valid Objective-C.

Comment: @Jack: That's not what your answer says. Your answer says "since C is how ObejctiveC implements itself under the hood (a class is just a struct) there is no way to know it in such way" which is incorrect.

Comment: @Jack: For one, an Objective-C class is not just a struct; an instance of a class is a struct, but a class itself is a *self-documenting* opaque type that contains the name of the class, the layout of an instance's ivars, its superclass, and so forth.

Comment: @Jack: For another, your answer states that it is not possible at runtime to perform reflection, which is as previously stated incorrect. Finally, while you're absolutely correct that `NSCoding` is the correct way to do object persistence, the rest of your answer is still wrong and should be corrected.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: I'm speaking about reflection __to know the address of a field by using ObjectiveC directly__, I think it is quite clear.

Comment: @Jack: To whit: `ivar_getOffset()`.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: That's not ObjectiveC. That's a fuction of ObjectiveC runtime. You are not using a feature of the language for your purpose, you are using a C function that provides an utility. Actually that utility function could even not exist in another ObjectiveC implementation so relying on it could be a good or bad idea.

Comment: @Jack You are making an artificial distinction that does not exist in Objective-C. *Valid C is valid Objective-C*. Objective-C doesn't solely comprise the message dispatch syntax and `@` keywords; it also covers the features of the underlying C language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20127/discussion-between-jack-and-jonathan-grynspan)

Comment: I know that offsets are implementation specific, but with what I am doing, I get an implementation specific mask. I am sorry I did not respond immediately, I was off for a while. As I said above, I need not only offsets, but also which variables are pointers and which only values - that is the key of my question.